# Upgrading an Amazon EC2 instance from t1.micro to medium, instance storage remains same

Tags: unix, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, upgrade

We have been using micro instance till our development phase. But now, as we are about to go live, we want to upgrade our instance to type medium.

I followed these simple steps: stop the running instance, change instance type to medium and then start the instance again. I can see the instance is upgraded in terms of the memory. But the storage still shows to be 8GB. But according to the configuration mentioned, a m1.medium type instance should have 1x410GB storage.

Am I doing anything wrong or missing out something? Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind, EBS storage (which you are currently using) and Instance storage (which is what you are looking for) are two different things in EC2.

EBS storage is similar to a SAN volume. It exists outside of the host. You can create multiple EBS volumes of up to 1TB and attach them to any instance size. Smaller instances have lower available bandwidth to EBS volumes so they will not be able to effectively take advantage of all that many volumes.

Instance storage is essentially hard drives attached to the host. While its included in the instance cost, it comes with some caveats. It is not persistent. If you stop your instance, or the host fails for any reason, the data stored on the instance store will be lost. For this reason, it has to be explicitly enabled when the instance is first launched.

Generally, its not recommended that to use instance storage unless you are conformable with and have designed your infrastructure around the non-persistance of instance storage.

Comment: Yes and no.  The root file systems are also EBS storage, but they cannot be accessed like the "standard" EBS storages (i. e. from other instances).  But they produce cost (for instance) like any other EBS volume.

Answer (score 2):

The sizes mentioned for the instance types are just these defaults.  If you create an image from a running micro instance, it will get that storage size as default, even if this image later is started as medium.

But you can change the storage size when launching the instance:

[image]

You also can change the default storage size when creating an image:

[image]

*WARNING:*  This will resize the storage size.  It will not necessarily resize the partition existing on it nor will it necessarily resize the file system on that partition.  On Linux it resized everything automagically (IIRC), on a Windows instance you will have to resize your stuff yourself.  For other OSes I have no idea.

Comment: So how should I go about it. 
1. Create an image of the running micro instance.
2. Launch a new instance from the image, and before launching, changing the storage size?

While choosing the storage size, will they restrict me to 410GB [as mentioned], or can I choose anything and they will charge me accordingly?

Comment: If you want to start a larger instance just this once, set the storage size upon launching.  If you want to start instance with the larger storage size more often, I suggest to create a new image with the larger storage size.  I've never tried to acquire more than some hundred GB, so I guess the limit of 410GB applies.  What are limits good for, otherwise? ;-)

Comment: May be I am acting too stupid, but when I change the instance type, it doesnt ask me to choose the storage space, though I remember to have chosen while creating instance for the first time.

The alternative I can see is: 1. Create snapshot of the volume I have. 2. Create a new volume from that snapshot, and while doing so we can increase the storage space to 410GB. 3. Attach this new volume to the increased instance.

Is it a right way of doing things? And will my data be safe?

Comment: Right, there's a shortcut to change the instance type that unfortunately does not allow changing the storage size (or other properties).  You will have to create a new instance from your image.  And if you want to have the new size as a default, you will have to create a new image.

Comment: I added a warning to my answer which might or might not apply to your situation.

Comment: Yes, I think now I have the similar problem as you mentioned in the warning. My volumes are created as shown inside the volume section, but on the server it is showing only 8GB. It is a Linux instance. So is it just about creating new partitions?

Comment: Did you create a new image with the new size or did you just create a new instance with a larger storage?  Maybe just if you do it with a new image the automagic applies.

Comment: I created an image from the running instance. And then launched it as an instance.

Comment: And what is it about EBS and Instance Store volumes? I increased the root volume to 100GB and added 310GB as type EBS. I do not actually need to much space. 25-30 GB is fine. Will I be charged separately for these volumes?

Comment: About chargings I don't know exactly, so better watch your account info regularly (always a good idea anyway).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation. I created a m2.medium instance of 400 GB, but when I log into the shell and issue the command

`df -h`

... it shows an 8 GB partition.

However, the command

`sudo fdisk -l`

showed that the device was indeed 400 GB. The problem is that Amazon created a default 8 GB partition on it, and that partition needs to be expanded to the full size of the device. The command to do this is:

`sudo resize2fs -f /dev/xvda1`

where /dev/xvda1 is the mounted root volume. Use the 'df -h' command to be sure you have the right volume name.

Then simply reboot the instance, log in again, and you'll see the fdisk command now says there's nearly 400 GB available space. Problem solved.